# Get the relative path of RegistryKey

Tags: c#, registry

I have a System.Win32.RegistryKey object that points to, for example, "HKCU\Software\Test".  The .Name property is populated with the absolute path.  Is there a way to get only the current (relative) key name?

In the example above, I am looking for just the "Test" part of the path.  I am looking for the Registry equivelent to System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName without having to parse the path manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`.

The `Path.*` functions (except for `GetFullPath()`) are purely string manipulation functions and work fine even with non-filesystem paths.

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName` will throw an `ArgumentException` when the key contains any character a directory cannot exist. I.E. `|` (pipe). Use `key.Name.Substring(0, key.Name.LastIndexOf('\\'))` instead.

Comment: That should be `key.Name.Substring(key.Name.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1)` to get the relative part.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(string)` which works just fine with registry paths.

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for the relative value (just Test) not the absolute full path. The `GetDirectoryName` method returns the absolute path. 
The method you want to use is:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(subkey.Name);
```

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)